# Back-end doesn't send me a response (JWT) while using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, backend

I don't get a `token JWT` after send a request to the restcontroller.
I tried to rewrite, but this didn't solve the problem.
I'm confused becuase I thought that I need to enter the default security password, but `"Basic auth"` is disabled.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                    requests -> requests
                            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/auth").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            )
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
            //.addFilterAfter(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

    return http.build();
}
```

---

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class AuthController
{
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthToken(@RequestBody AuthRequestDTO authRequestDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequestDTO.getUsername(), authRequestDTO.getPassword()));
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid username or password"), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authRequestDTO.getUsername());

        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthResponseDTO(token));
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUjN5.png)

Comment: Well, you explicitily configured POST to `/api/v1/auth` as secured (`hasRole("ADMIN")`), which looks wrong - at this point, you have nothing in security context yet. Generally, the sign-in/sign-up requests are `.permitAll()`, while all the others are protected - e.g., closing the customizer chain with `.anyRequest().authenticated();`

Comment: @SergVasylchak **/api/v1/auth** only for Admin. I don't have others controller and this is like test controller

Comment: You need to be more specific on how this should work. Assuming it's just username/password login, then the user has no authorities yet. `PreAuthorize` does a check _before_ it allows access to the endpoint. If you need additional checks, like user type, do those checks in the endpoint. e.g. `if userIsNotAdmin then return 401`

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a loop here. for a user to login they need to be an admin, and for them to be an admin they must login first !! this does not work. usually login endpoint should not have any authorization required

Comment: My **admin user** has admin license in database

Comment: so admin user is already registered, but he cant login, so he cant prove to the system that he is an admin.